# How many matches can I expect for a Y24 Dna test

Tags: y-dna

I have taken a basic DNA test from Ancestry and got over 700 dna matches.  Based on this how many matches can I expect to get from a Y24 Test

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  While awaiting answers perhaps look over some of the frequently asked questions about Y-DNA: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y-dna?sort=frequent

Comment: Terry, this question is not very clear. Would you mind editing your question using the [edit] button below your post, to provide some clarification please?

Comment: The Ancestry DNA test doesn't address Y-DNA, so there isn't a basis on which your question can be answered -- you need to know your Y-haplogroup first.

Answer (score 2):

You may get a dozens matches for Y24 tests. It does not correlate with AncestryDNA's number of matches, because they are totally different and tests different things.

AncestryDNA test is co-called autosomal test. Like FamilyFinder from competitive laboratory, FTDNA. It gathers data about your 22 pairs of autosomal chromosomes and X chromosome. It tests for relationships on small timeframes and limited generally to 4-5 generations to MCRA.

Y-DNA tests are of two kinds: Y-STR and SNP tests. You talk about Y-STR test. It determines the number of some fixed markers and compares it to the same markers from other man. This test is applicable only to man. Woman doesn't have Y chromosome. Such test allows to prove the relationship between many-many generations. It gives the ability to predict your so-called haplogroup. How many matches do you have is in connection how much people from the same haplogroup live on the Earth. And how much people are tested.

Just some examples.
I have

- 0 matches on Y-DNA111;
- 2 matches on Y-DNA67;
- 5 matches on Y-DNA35;
- about 200 matches on Y-DNA25;
- about 1900 matches on Y-DNA11;

I belong to I-M253 (aka I1) haplogroup.